# How to communicate with IoT gateway with C#

Tags: sensors, azure

I'm a C# web developer and I just started handling an IoT project. My goal is to have this set up:

> PIR Sensors > IoT Gateway > Website (ASP.NET Web Application C#)

For now, I have PIR sensors (BLE) and [AD810 Alarm Control Box](http://www.szkpl.com/product/detail2/l/en/id/26.html) from Shenzhen Kaipule. It comes with a mobile app so it communicate via WIFI. The issue is that their mobile app and documentation is in Chinese and I could not read it. I need help to communicate with the Alarm box using C#. I am also open for suggestion for an alternative IoT Gateway that is easy to communicate using C#.

Update: I managed to use Azure Digital Twins because it's an ideal solution for this project. The tutorial only simulates a device and I would want to know where do I register an actual device to the Azure Digital Twins so that I can have the DeviceConnectionString to the sample project?

Comment: What did you try so far? If you elaborate what's your problem someone might be able to help you.

Comment: So far I tried to use Azure Digital Twins since this is the most ideal solution for my project. I finished the tutorial for their sample project but I never get to see how I can connect the actual device to the application. The tutorial only used a simulation of a device.

on the appsettings.json, you will able to add DeviceConnectionString but where do I get to register my device to the Azure Digital Twin?